# Python: How to Exclude Dataset Import From ggplot?

Tags: python, ggplot2, import

Title is self-explanatory. How can I exclude the import of the datasets that come with ggplot when I do:

from ggplot import *

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to exclude the dataset while importing a module. But you can easily remove them by calling below one line command the delete the dataset after you import it. I use it as a workaround and it works pretty well.

```
from ggplot import *
del diamonds, chopsticks, meat, movies, mpg, mtcars, pageviews, pigeons, salmon
```